# Why doesn't "ipconfig /flushdns" completely wipe your DNS?

Tags: command-line, dns, cache, ipconfig

I've consistently had a problem where "ipconfig /flushdns" + restarting computer doesn't get rid of all the DNS records.

Should it completely flush any and all records in DNS?
Why doesn't it usually happen like this?
Is there some kind of restriction?

Comment: You have some good answers to your hypothetical question.  What problem are you trying to overcome?

Comment: The "success" report of /flushdns is "hardcoded", It just always reports success.  
If it is launched with Admin rights (right click) then it works. Without launching it as admin (even if you are logged in as admin) it just fails and reports success.  
I wonder if asking to burn some microsoft developers slowly on a stick would be political incorrect ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If one asked "why do some entries remain in `ipconfig /displaydns` even after I have flushed them with `/flushdns`?", it would have several possible answers:

1. A program is repeatedly resolving some domain, so its information gets cached almost immediately again.
2. The DNS Resolver has the handling of some special names hardcoded (such as `localhost`).
3. The DNS Resolver automatically **reads your `/etc/hosts`** (actually `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`) and uses it to fill the Resolver cache so that these names wouldn't have to be actually looked up on DNS. It's a nice trick to avoid re-reading /etc/hosts every time a name has to be resolved.

---

If one asked "why, after I change something in my domain and run `/flushdns`, I still don't see my changes?"

**It is physically impossible to flush all records in DNS, because DNS – the Domain Name System – is hosted on many servers over the entire Internet, and you would have to destroy all of them.**

What `ipconfig` accesses is **your computer's local cache** of information looked up from DNS; if you flush the cache on your computer and try to access any domain, the computer has to ask the configured DNS server again.

However, the configured DNS server, be it your router's, your ISP's, or a public one (e.g. Google's), has *its own* cache. Once someone asks the DNS server at `8.8.8.8` about the domain `superuser.com`, it gets cached on *that* server as well. So in many cases there might be three, maybe even four, layers of caching: in Windows, in your router/modem/gateway, at your ISP, and maybe a second layer deeper at the ISP.

Comment: So then by releasing your ip `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` you're essentially getting a new IP assigned that other DNS servers do not recognize?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: These two commands have no relation at all to the ones explained above. They do not do anything to DNS; they work with DHCP – `/release` "returns" the current IP address lease, and `/renew` tries to extend the current one – or requests a new one, *possibly* with a different IP address or with different DNS server settings, but it's up to the router what address it issues a lease for.

Comment: There may be yet another hidden location for old ip-numbers. 1. I flushed the DNS using admin rights. 2. nslookup gives me the new ip-number. 3. I verified the host is not in the hosts file. 4. ping still connects to the old ip! Where is this old setting hiding? ipconfig /all shows there is more than 1 DNS server. In my case the old ip-number is hiding on the 2nd DNS server: ping apparantly uses the DNS server with the old ip-number and nslookup by default apparently uses the DNS that has the new ip number.

Answer (score 1):

Any A (host) records will be re-added to your cache upon restarting your machine.

Stopping and starting the dnscache will not change this either. Some Host records will automatically repopulate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the discussion. I changed the A record IP for a host and ping would hit the old IP, but nslookup showed the correct new IP. Flushing DNS didn't help.Sure enough, the hostname and old IP was in the host file. Problem solved.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1145065)